# Cannot install matplotlib

Tags: pip

`pip` cannot install `matplotlib`. Why won't it work?

It just hangs when I do `pip install matplotlib`.

```
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-1.5.1.tar.gz
```

The workaround to finally get it installed was to download the archive from sourceforge. I'm going to try it again to verify that there is a problem with the package.

[image]

Comment: What exactly are the commands that you use? Can you add that to your question?

Comment: @edwinksl I updated the question and will try again if the problem is reproducable. I finally could install it but from sourceforge.

Comment: Note that `pip install matplotlib` will appear to hang but the installation process is actually still well alive. Try the same command again and wait for a while.

Comment: @edwinksl I waited several minutes after it reached 100 %. I'm going to try again now.

Comment: Not reproducible even on another computer. When I try again it works. What happened was it stalled at 100 %.

Comment: That is rather strange. I don't think I have seen this before. But it seems you at least managed to install it after all.

Comment: @edwinksl It reached 100 % and stalled. I updated the question with a screenshot. Maybe it is not a bug but something random in my environment.

Comment: Yeah, possibly. I was not able to reproduce your error; `pip install matplotlib` works on my machine with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Did you try to upgrade your pip or clean your pip cache?

Comment: @NgocThangPham I tried to upgrade my pip. I didn't try clean the cache. when I downloaded the package from sourceforge then it installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I have just figured it out, try installing the dependencies manually first

```
cycler>=0.10       
kiwisolver>=1.0.1  
python-dateutil>=2.7 
numpy>=1.16        
pillow>=6.2.0       
pyparsing>=2.2.1   
six
```

For me it was on an armv7 architecture and I was installing from requirements.txt and it would hang on the installation of matplotlib but when I commented out matplotlib and installed everything else from the requirements.txt including the above listed libs it doesn't hang anymore.